# saving hashtable using c so that random access is faster

Tags: c, database

I am writing a C code (call it database generation) processes an input file and generated a number in range [1,10^8] alongwith a sequence of float values whose length is fixed but unknown followed by 3 integers. All values are separated by space

Example:

```
19432 23.45 32.12 45.76 ...(156 such float values) 4 6 106
```

This will be one line of database where first number is hash index (one to 10^8) , and last 3 integers denote the x,y coordinated and document ID respectively.

Our database is saved in file xyz which has following content

```
2341 34.67 43.13 ... (234 such float values) 5 8 123
2352 46.92 41.89 ... (51 such float values) 1 9 145
2352 46.92 41.89 ... (98 such float values) 2 7 12
2359 12.71 72.90 ... (141 such float values) 8 12 13
```

The starting number (hash index value) will always be in non-decreasing order in database as we proceed from one line to next.

I have another C code (call it retrieval) which takes hash index value as input and should output all lines starting with that value.

I have 2 questions

1. How can I make sure that retrieval directly jumps to line containing asked hash index value skipping the starting lines of database so that its response is fast.
2. When I get another input file for database and its hash index value is 2352. How do i add another line starting with 2352 at its proper position in database?

I am considering following approach which is not ideal, as the database won't be organised in required non-decreasing order of hash index values. Also, database is split into 2 components. One contains byte offset entries for each hash index and another is the database file presented above.

It involves

```
(1)byte-offset.txt of the form
2341 byte-pos-1
2352 byte-pos-2
2359 byte-pos-3
2352 byte-pos-4
(2)database.txt of the form
2341 34.67 43.13 ... (234 such float values) 5 8 123
2352 46.92 41.89 ... (51 such float values) 1 9 145
2359 12.71 72.90 ... (141 such float values) 8 12 13
2352 46.92 41.89 ... (98 such float values) 2 7 12
```

the only good thing about it is that new entries can be appended  to end in each file as database grows when we get more data.

Comment: Why not use an existing database library like sqlite3 or dbm.

Comment: Have you considered using B+-trees?

Comment: If you don't have to build your own database for whatever reason, yes go ahead and use sqlite which you can use in your C program.

See: https://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html

Comment: i was looking for database that has fast lookup and can be incorporated in my c program . I am not so good at programming so coding b+- tree would be difficult for me . sqlite looks good . i will try to use it .